# should data below be foreign key or primary key?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

**Session**

```
SessionId (PK) SessionName  SessionDuration  TotalMarks  SessionWeight  ModuleId (FK)
1             AAA          01:00:00        30         20            1
```

**Penalty**

```
SessionId (PK)  PenaltyEnalbed
1               1
```

My question is that as `SessionId` in Penalty Table refers to the `Session` Table, should `SessionId` in penalty table be a primary key or a foriegn key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be foreign key but in penalty there should also be an Id to set as primary key. So in penalty it should be ID(PK) SessionId (FK)  PenaltyEnalbed

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350029/can-a-foreign-key-be-created-if-both-fields-are-non-unique) Another db question I have if you want to look

Answer (score 1):

`SessionID` in table `Penalty` should be define as `FOREIGN KEY` since you have mentioned that it refers on column `SessionID` of table `Session`.

```
CREATE TABLE Session
(
    SessionID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    -- OTHER columns here...
);

CREATE TABLE Penalty
(
    SessionID INT NOT NULL,
    -- OTHER columns here...,
    CONSTRAINT penalty_fk FOREIGN KEY (SessionID)
        REFERENCES Session(SessionID)
);
```

Comment: Only just beaten by minutes. I have another db question if you want a look, my last db question before I make db [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350029/can-a-foreign-key-be-created-if-both-fields-are-non-unique)