# How to combine fields in foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-key-relationship

Question Table:

```
QuestionId (PK)  QuestionNo  QuestionContent SessionId
11               1           blah            4
12               2           blah blah       4
13               1           BLAH            5
14               2           BLAH BLAH       5
```

Image_Question Table:

```
Image_QuestionId (PK) ImageId (FK) SessionId (FK) QuestionNo
4                     6              4              1
```

Session Table:

```
SessionId SessionName
4         DFOFK
5         FEOWF
```

Got three tables above. Now if you look at the `SessionId` in the `Image Question` Table, it is a foreign key to the `Session` Table so that if I click on the `SessionId` value in the `Image_Question` Table, it will display the `Session` details from the `Session` Table.

Now I have another column in the `Image Question` table which is not yet assigned a foreign key and that is the `QuestionNo` field. Now this is not a primary key in any table but I need to use this field in order to know which question an image belongs to. Anyway that  isn't the issue.

My issue is this, if I just set `QuestionNo` in the `Image_Question` table to `FK`, then if I click on the `QuestionNo's` value in the `Image_Question` table, then it will display all `QuestionNo` which is `1` in all sessions. I don't want this, I want to look up the `QuestionNo` within the `SessionId` the Question number belongs to.

So my question is how in SQL do I set the `QuestionNo` foreign key so that it joins together both the `SessionId` and `QuestionNo` fields so that it creates a unique `SessionId/QuestionNo` constraint.

Comment: so why dont you use questionID instead of questionNo in image_question? this way there would be no ambiguity

Comment: What @WKordos said. `QuestionNo` is not a candidate key. Use `QuestionId`

Comment: You shouldn't and can't do that. Besides that's what questionid is for

Comment: Having QuestionNo in the Image_Question makes your schema denormalized.

Comment: Hi guys, the reason I cannot use questionId is because a user creates questions, now they upload an image while creating a question. The questions are only inserted into db after submission but uploading of image files happen before submission. I used question numbers in web page to determine which questions each image belong to as like I said I can't use questionid to do this as questions havn't been inserted

Comment: Is there a way then where we can place the question number and sessionid each image belongs to in a temp table then replace it with questionid after questionid is submitted for each question?

Comment: why yes there is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14350029/1914530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the image, you know the SessionId and QuestionId so you can enter this with a NULL question first and get the QuestionId and use this in your image table. When you do get the question info you can update the question table.

HOWEVER, this is not good practice.

You should not commit the image to the question until you commit the question, these should be kept in your business layer until you have the whole of the information - then commit them to permed ant storage.